# How to capitalize only first letter of first word in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to capital only first letter of first  word of list and remaining all words to be in lower case in ascending order of the length of word.

```
z=['The' ,'lines', 'are', 'printed', 'in', 'reverse', 'order']
z.sort(key=len) 
print(" ".join(x.lower() for x in z))
```

I want the result like this in ascending order of length.

In the are lines order printed reverse  :

```
z=['The' ,'lines', 'are', 'printed', 'in', 'reverse', 'order']
# i tried like this 
z.sort(key=len)
s=[]
for x in z:
     if (x==0):
        s.append(z[0].capitalize())
     else:
        s.append(z[x].lower())
```

Actual output that I am trying to get:

```
In the are lines order printed reverse
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

> ```
> for x in z:    # ['in', 'The', 'are', 'lines', 'order', 'printed', 'reverse']
>      if (x==0):
>         s.append(z[0].capitalize())
>      else:
>         s.append(z[x].lower())
> ```

does not work because each `x` is a word from `z` - it will *never* be equal to `0` so all that things added to `s` are lower case version of your words.

---

You can [use `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index of all elements in the list while iterating it.

The first element has to use `.title()` casing, all others `.lower()`:

```
z= ['The' ,'lines', 'are', 'printed', 'in', 'reverse', 'order']
z.sort(key=len) 

# reformat capitalization based in index, any number != 0 is true-thy
z = [ a.lower() if idx else a.capitalize() for idx, a in enumerate(z) ]

print(" ".join(z))
```

Output:

```
In the are lines order printed reverse
```

---

`z = [ a.lower() if idx else a.capitalize() for idx, a in enumerate(z) ]` is a list comprehension - as normal loop it would look like:

```
s = []
for idx, word in enumerate(z):
    if idx:   # any idx > 0 is True-thy
        s.append(word.lower())
    else:
        s.append(word.capitalize())
# print the joined s
```

You can learn what *python* considers `True` for non-boolean values here: [Truth-value-testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a `for` loop (or [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)), you can just use the [`capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) method if you're sure the type of the first value will always be [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str).

In other words, call the `capitalize()` method on the first value of the list and change the value at index `0` to its result.

For example, the following code:

```
z = ['the' ,'lines', 'are', 'printed', 'in', 'reverse', 'order']
z.sort(key = len)
z[0] = z[0].capitalize()
print(z)
```

Should output:

```
['In', 'the', 'are', 'lines', 'order', 'printed', 'reverse']
```

And if you join it using a space, like this:

```
z = " ".join(z)
```

It'll output:

```
'In the are lines order printed reverse'
```

**WARNING:** if you do decide to use `join` on `z`, you'll be changing its type from `list` to `str`, indexes will still work but `z[0]` will no longer equal `In`, it'll be `I`.

---

If you want to be extremely thorough and ensure that all other words are lower cased, you can use the following list comprehension instead of the aforementioned technique:

```
z = ['the' ,'lines', 'are', 'printed', 'in', 'reverse', 'order']
z.sort(key = len)
z = [(x.capitalize() if i == 0 else x) for (i, x) in enumerate(z)]
```

Expected output:

```
['In', 'the', 'are', 'lines', 'order', 'printed', 'reverse']
```

Output when joined using `" ".join(z)`:

```
'In the are lines order printed reverse'
```

Good luck.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks for pointing that out! Completely skipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this simple code, I know it's not the most concise but it does the job:

```
z=['The' ,'lines', 'are', 'printed', 'in', 'reverse', 'order']
s=[]
for x in z:   
    wordup=(x[0].upper() + x[1:len(x)]) 
    s.append(wordup)
print(s)
```

x is not an integer, we are iterating strings x from the list z

wordup is the concatenation of the first letter of (x) capitalized, and the rest of (x) : this means from index 1 to end of x (len(x))

Using the 'capitalize()' method:

```
z=['in', 'The', 'are', 'lines', 'order', 'printed', 'reverse']
s=[]
for x in z: 
    s.append(x.capitalize())
print(s)
```